# Get more than 1 message from Gmail.Thread

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When i run this script, i get 1 from adress, i would like to get the first 5 from adresses i try to set `GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 5)[0];` but that does not work, what do i need to do if i need to have 5 or more? Now it only process 1 mail/thread.

```
// log the sender of the messages in the thread
 var firstThread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 1)[0];
 var messages = firstThread.getMessages();
 for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
   Logger.log(messages[i].getFrom());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 5);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    Logger.log(message.getFrom());
```

=)